# Difference between probabilistic generative, discriminative models and "discriminant functions"?

Tags: probability, discriminant-analysis, graphical-model, generative-models

I have been thoroughly confused by a bunch of online resources regarding this issue. I would really like a simple explanation about the differences between generative and discriminative approaches, and where "discriminant functions" figure in all this. I would especially appreciate any explanation or a pointer toward a resource without any of the "generative models generate random data according to some distribution..." standard explanation. This explanation is very vague to grasp for someone unfamiliar with this area and especially this explanation does nothing to describe the motivation for using generative vs. discriminative models.